# Why create-react-app changed App.js component to function based component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

As I noticed, it seems `create-react-app` changed `app.js` class component based in a function component,

any idea why they did this?

Comment: Did you try reading the logs for an official answer?

Comment: Still didn't find any explanation in logs why they changed it, will look more as soon as I access a pc

Answer (score 30, accepted):

React itself is moving away from class-based components.

A quotes from this doc: [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#classes-confuse-both-people-and-machines)

> In addition to making code reuse and code organization more difficult, we’ve found that classes can be a large barrier to learning React. You have to understand how this works in JavaScript, which is very different from how it works in most languages. You have to remember to bind the event handlers. Without unstable syntax proposals, the code is very verbose. People can understand props, state, and top-down data flow perfectly well but still struggle with classes. The distinction between function and class components in React and when to use each one leads to disagreements even between experienced React developers.
>
> Additionally, React has been out for about five years, and we want to make sure it stays relevant in the next five years. As Svelte, Angular, Glimmer, and others show, ahead-of-time compilation of components has a lot of future potential. Especially if it’s not limited to templates. Recently, we’ve been experimenting with component folding using Prepack, and we’ve seen promising early results. However, we found that class components can encourage unintentional patterns that make these optimizations fall back to a slower path. Classes present issues for today’s tools, too. For example, classes don’t minify very well, and they make hot reloading flaky and unreliable. We want to present an API that makes it more likely for code to stay on the optimizable path.
>
> To solve these problems, Hooks let you use more of React’s features without classes. Conceptually, React components have always been closer to functions. Hooks embrace functions, but without sacrificing the practical spirit of React. Hooks provide access to imperative escape hatches and don’t require you to learn complex functional or reactive programming techniques.